# Storing Session Variable on button click, HTML, PHP

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

I am having trouble storing Session variable on a button click. I am trying do this without use of a form. Here is the code I have for my html and PHP.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['oldsignin'])) {
   $username = $_GET['oldusername'];
   $_SESSION['oldusername']= $username;
  }
?>
```

Below is my html file:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Username:</label>
        <input id = "oldusername" type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
        <a class="usersignin" name="oldsignin" data-role="button" style="background: blue; color: white;">Sign In</a>
</div>
```

Thanks Guys for your help and suggestions.

Comment: You need to specify the `name` attribute as `oldusername` > `name="user"`

Comment: You could to it way easier using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

PHP processes before the HTML file is sent to the client browser, so for inputted data to be processed, a page reload (form submission) needs to take place I'm afraid.

(unless you use AJAX, you'll need to look that up)